# How do I make a left-floated div take up 100% of the remaining space?

Tags: html, css

If I have a container with 75% width and two columns inside, left and right, with left being 10em in width, how do I get the right container to take up 100% of the space remaining?

I tried this with no luck:

```css
html, body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
#container {
    position:relative;
    width:75%;
    margin:0 auto;
    background:blue;
}
#left-container {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    height:100%;
    width:10em;
    background:red;
}
#right-container {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    background:yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="left-container">Left</div>
    <div id="right-container">Right</div>
</div>
```

I can do this easily with percentages, but I need left to be a fixed 10em width.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can make a box element take up the remainder of the space by removing `float: left`, removing the `width` and adding `overflow:hidden` to the *right* `div`

## [Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/J2J8X/2/)

```css
#right-container {
    position:relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    height:100%;
    background:yellow;
}
```

Comment: Oh wow, that was far simpler than I thought it would be. I'd have never thought of this. Thank you!

Comment: @MichaelN You're welcome, I remember having this problem when I started and it took me *hours* before I realized this. It's a nice trick, don't forget it :)

Comment: This work on Firefox but not on Chrome, bro. My Chrome version is 51. Thanks for your answer anyway, I'm looking for this issue

Comment: @Ben I just checked Firefox and it works fine in the latest version.

Comment: Yes, as I said it works on Firefox, doesn't work on Chrome (version 51).

Comment: You're not on the latest Chrome. I also checked Chrome, worked fine. I'm on 54

Answer (score 1):

There are at least 2 options for this kind of problem at this moment (2016) using CSS3, far simpler solutions than the accepted answer, which is kind of a "hack" using `overflow:hidden`

- using `flexbox`

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#container {
  width: 75%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: blue;
  display: flex
}
#left-container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 10em;
  background: red;
}
#right-container {
  height: 100%;
  flex:1;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="left-container">Left</div>
  <div id="right-container">Right</div>
</div>
```

---

- using `calc()`

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#container {
  width: 75%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: blue;
}
#left-container {
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  width: 10em;
  background: red;
}
#right-container {
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  width: calc(100% - 10em);
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="left-container">Left</div>
  <div id="right-container">Right</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to put a left margin on the `#right-container` div:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<style media="all">
html, body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
#container {
    position:relative;
    width:75%;
    margin:0 auto;
    background:blue;
}
#left-container {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    height:100%;
    width:10em;
    background:red;
}
#right-container {
    position:relative;
    margin-left: 11em;
    height:100%;
    background:yellow;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>

<div id="container">
    <div id="left-container">
        Left
    </div>
    <div id="right-container">
        Right
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add-in another option as below:

```
#header-left-section {
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1000;
}
#header-right-section {
    height: 90px;
    width:100%;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#header-right-section ins,
#header-right-section div{float:right}
```

The left div just take enough space for its inside stuff.
The right part take 100% the width, and left part stays above it only left(by z-index).
Last css line is just to make inner stuff if of right div to be float on the right.